# How to switch UIViewController programatically for tvOS with Swift?

Tags: swift, tvos

### Question:

How do I correctly switch between different `UIControllerView` programmatically for `tvOS` with `Swift`?

### Details:

For example, by default when I create a `tvOS` project in `Xcode` I have `FirstViewController` and a `SecondViewController` created. Is it possible to create a `ThirdViewController` not defined in the tab bar controller that I can switch to programmatically whenever I want?

Comment: `tvOS` works a lot like `iOS`, it depends a lot on how you want to display your third controller (push, modally), but yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add more vc programmatically in TVOS.
If you have story board with `tabbarcontroller` change it class to custom `tabbarcontroller` and inside that you can add more view controllers.
Something like this

```
class DashBoardTabVC : UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        self.viewControllers?.append(vc)
    }
}
```

And you can select any of them like

```
self.selectedIndex  = 0
```